# Normal order and applicative order evaluation in Scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

For the 1st example given on site: [View-Site](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jastr/6001/spring06/r23.pdf), my understanding is that normal order evaluates to `[6;1;1]` and applicative order evaluates to `[6;2;2]`

Can anyone please confirm my assessment?

Regards,
darkie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let's go through the steps of evaluating `(cons res v)` with normal-order evaluation:

`v` has been defined as `(cons a (cons b ’()))`, so we have `cons res (cons a (cons b ’()))`. `res` is defined as `(foo ...)`, so we have

```
(cons (foo (begin (set! a (+ a 1)) a)
           (begin (set! b (* b 2)) b))
      (cons a (cons b ’())))
```

Lastly `foo x y` is defined as `(+ x y y)`, so by substituting `(begin (set! a (+ a 1)) a)` for `x` and `(begin (set! b (* b 2)) b)` for `y`, we get:

```
(cons (+ (begin (set! a (+ a 1)) a)
         (begin (set! b (* b 2)) b)
         (begin (set! b (* b 2)) b))
      (cons a (cons b ’())))
```

So now let's evaluate this: To get the result of cons, we first need to evaluate its first argument, `(+ ...)`. So we first need to evaluate the first argument of `+` which is `(begin (set! a (+ a 1)) a)`. This evaluates to 2, so the value of `a` is now 2 and the first argument to `+` is also 2. Now we do the same thing with the second argument. This also evaluates to 2 and sets b to 2. The third argument is `(begin (set! b (* b 2)) b)` again, so the value of `b` is now 4 and the third argument is 4. So the first argument to `cons` is the result `(+ 2 2 4)`, which is 8 and the values of `a` and `b` are 2 and 4.

Now we need to evaluate the second argument, `(cons a (cons b ’()))`. So since the value of `a` and `b` are 2 and 4, the end result is `(8 2 4)`.